# how to check a function object is valid or not

Tags: erlang

I want to check one input parameter which is function object or not. The erlang module's `is_function` and `fun_info` are not ok, because they don't the function is really exported by the module or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you're trying to understand whether a function is exported or not from a given module, you can use the [erlang:function_exported/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#function_exported-3) function:

> Returns true if the module Module is loaded and contains an exported
>   function Function/Arity; otherwise false.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are much more familiar with Erlang library than me.

Comment: `erlang:function_exported/3` isn't the best choice because it will return `false` if the module is not loaded, even if a particular function is exported. `module_info`, as suggested by the other answer, could be better (module `code` contains a few other choices as well).

Answer (score 1):

To know if a function `sort/2` is exported by a module `lists`, *whether it is loaded or not* (see [Amiramix comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278574/how-to-check-a-function-object-is-valid-or-not#comment21523782_10278727)), you can use:

```
lists:member({sort, 2}, lists:module_info(exports)).
```

If you don't mind the function Arity, you can use:

```
case lists:keyfind(sort, 1, lists:module_info(exports)) of
    {sort, _} -> true;
    false -> false
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

module:module_info(exports)

[module_info](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html#id74109)

Comment: I know this function, but I think there exists maybe much better choice. Thank you.